# Matlab: How to save plots of patches / fill() automatically in the code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

quick question: I'm creating "random" polygons using either the patch() or the fill() function in Matlab. This works quite good and it is plotted correctly.

However, I need to at least save a few hundres polygons as images to my hard drive for working with them later - so I'm looking for a way to directly save the image in my function rather than saving each polygon myself using the file-menu.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmm easier than thought.

    patch(xdata,ydata,'r')
    axis square
    print('-djpeg', FILENAME);

did the trick...not very good though

Comment: any better solution is very much appreciated

Comment: Why is `print('-djpeg', FILENAME);` "not very good"? You can probably fix whatever it is you don't like (resolution, font size, etc) programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use the `print` function, but I would not use the `jpeg` device. JPEG is **never** the right format for plots (you will get a lot of artifacts near all your lines).

If you need a bitmap image, try the `png` or `tiff` device. If you don't need a bitmap, use the appropriate vector image format: `fig` is the native MATLAB format (which allows you to edit the plot afterwards), so this is the best one if you stick with MATLAB for all your operations. For exporting to other software, I would recommend `pdf` (works almost anywhere), `epsc` (EPS with color, great for LaTeX or inkscape), `wmf`/`emf` (Windows Metafile, so Windows only, but great for including the images in MS Office). Or you could of course use any of the other formats mentioned in the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) documentation.

Sometimes it's a pain in the neck to get the format of your image all right (especially with PDF output). Just take a look at the different [properties of your figure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html)  and more specifically the `PaperSize`, `PaperUnits` and `PaperPosition`.

The easiest way, and I guess the best solution, is to save as a `.fig` file. You can do this by using [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html):

```
h = figure;
% your plot commands here
saveas(h,'mFile.fig');
```

Afterwards, you can reload the image with the [`openfig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/openfig.html) function:

```
openfig('mFile.fig');
```

Comment: When automating plot generation, it's often very useful to create the figure as invisible using `h = figure('visible','off');`, render the stuff and use `close(h);` after the call to `saveas(h, ...);`.  I also recommend passing the axes handles explicitly in case you're using the parallel toolbox.  The global figure state is not synchronized and tends to get messed up when running multiple threads.

Comment: @André Caron: indeed, passing parameters explicitly can overcome many problems (not just with plotting or in combination with the parallel processing toolbox, but in general). Does that invisibility trick always work? Because in some situations it might be necessary to call `drawnow` before saving. In most cases I would also recommend to use the figure command as `figure('Name','Description of figure')` (and using `figure` explicitly instead of relying on `plot` to make a figure).

Comment: I've never had to use `drawnow` to update figures in general, so I can't guarantee that it updates invisible figures or not.  In any case, I've never had problems while using invisible figures to generate loads of figures for publishing results.

Answer (score 0):

Have to add this answer. [This function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) is helping a lot.

> This function saves a figure or single axes to one or more vector and/or bitmap file formats, and/or outputs a rasterized version to the workspace, with the following properties: 
>      - Figure/axes reproduced as it appears on screen 
>      - Cropped/padded borders (optional) 
>      - Embedded fonts (pdf only) 
>      - Improved line and grid line styles 
>      - Anti-aliased graphics (bitmap formats) 
>      - Render images at native resolution (optional for bitmap formats) 
>      - Transparent background supported (pdf, eps, png) 
>      - Semi-transparent patch objects supported (png only) 
>      - RGB, CMYK or grayscale output (CMYK only with pdf, eps, tiff) 
>      - Variable image compression, including lossless (pdf, eps, jpg) 
>      - Optionally append to file (pdf, tiff) 
>      - Vector formats: pdf, eps 
>      - Bitmap formats: png, tiff, jpg, bmp, export to workspace